# How to protect publically accessable MSK (kafka) broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

What is the best way to protect (enhance security) the publically accessible brokers?

There are only a few posts and docs from AWS that talk about Authentication, Encryption and Auth, but there's very little information regarding combining things like WAF to shield the brokers from internet attacks.

Comment: Have you considered building a very slim web app that receives data and pushes it to the broker? A lambda might do the trick, but I'm not sure how the performance would be if it needs to reconnect often to the brokers.

Answer (score 1):

A WAF is for HTTP/web applications, not generic TCP.

Authorization is only solution native to Kafka. Kafka will deny the requests if they are not authorized. I've never heard of Kafka being DDOS'd, for example...

The only thing a firewall would potentially add is IP allow/blocking, or request limiting.

You could use `fail2ban`, maybe, but that is also just based on `iptables` firewall-ing. However, that is a solution for running Kafka on your own, rather than a hosted solution, where you can run such software.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helps a lot. I think I used the wrong term "WAF", the question should be if there's any (AWS) layer 7 level product that shields the broker on an application level.  Or Kafka out of the box SASL or mTLS will be sufficient enough.

Comment: I don't know all the AWS services, but VPC / Firewall are the only things that can I think of to restrict network access to the server ports outside of any specific Kafka configs. Mentioned in the comments above, Kafka REST Proxy could be used (or your own HTTP API), then a WAF can be used there

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html), make sure your security groups as restrictive as possible:

> Important
>
> In addition to turning on public access, ensure that the cluster's security groups have inbound TCP rules that allow public access from your IP address. We recommend that you make these rules as restrictive as possible.

It is possible to DDOS Kafka brokers.

If IAM auth is enabled, authentication rate is [limited to 20 connections per second per broker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/limits.html#:%7E:text=Limits%20on%20TCP%20connections). If exceeded, clients will be throttled on auth level.

SASL/SCRAM and mTLS aren't throttled, but each connection takes memory, resources to authenticate, etc, so brokers will experience higher memory and CPU load.

Thus, securing access with security groups is essential.